# Kafka or Redis broker on embedded device

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, streaming

I would like to understand the implication of running a Kafka broker on a embedded device that has the spec 2GH and 4GB of memory. I am also interest in other's personal experience of running Redis or Kafka on a stringent hardware requirement.

I've been playing around a setup that logs the data from sensors on a Raspberry PI device, the logs is push out to a web client that display these data real-time. It's easier to use a broker such as Redis or Kafka to facilitate with the data stream but, I am unsure about the performance of running it on embedded device.

In short, how is it like to run a Redis or Kafka broker on a embedded device in terms of performance. By the way, this is done on a Python env.

Comment: I think you'll be limited more by disk IO than memory on such a machine. Don't expect hundreds of thousands TPS, but a thousand shouldn't be an issue. Note: You'll also need Zookeeper for Kafka, so running those 3 services on a single 4GB machine, I'd set at least 1GB heap for Kafka and maybe 512m for Zookeeper... If at all possible, setup a separate disk / USB for Kafka data

Comment: Anyway to limit the performance of Kafka so as to not use so much memory?? Also, does the memory grow over time when data stream becomes more demanding ?

Comment: "*does the memory grow over time when data stream becomes more demanding*" -- The JVM heap size has an initial setting. Kafka writes into heap first, and this size will grow until messages are written to disk, and messages can be GC'd but heap does not expand dynamically, no. And if you write to fast with limited space, then you get a OOM exception, and you lose data. You limit Kafka memory by configuring the Java heap size, as stated.